# Анализ макета и автоматическое создание html структуры

Tags: вёрстка, поиск-программ

В основном, я занимаюсь вёрсткой и соответственно, в подавляющем большинстве случаев имею дело с макетами (figma, реже photoshop). У макета всегда есть структура, вложенные элементы, основные блоки и т.д. Часто, код который я пишу, не сильно отличается от того, который есть в софте в котором находится макет (60% css кода находится в figma).

Следовательно, задаюсь вопросом, можно ли сделать (я знаю, что скорее всего ответ да) программу, которая будет анализировать макет и создавать структуру html?

Я не говорю о семантике, доступности, элементарно все теги могут быть div, но даже это упростило и ускорило бы работу. Так-же, я думаю что саму программу, можно написать основываясь именно на слоях в макете и их наименованиях, а именно, если слой "header" следовательно создать тег header и т.д

Сам вопрос: есть ли у вас примерное видение того, как это можно сделать? Какие технологии использовать?
Возможно, уже есть сервисы?

Пы.сы. Пожалуйста, не стоит отвечать "ищи в интернете", "думай сам" и т.д. Это я итак буду делать, просто задаю вопрос для людей, кому этот вопрос кажется очевидным, ввиду большего опыта и наличия знаний или же людей, кому это тоже кажется интересным.

Comment: познакомьтесь с css grid-template-areas и всем прочим доступным в грид-модели https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines и сможете описать весь макет сами парой строк =) а там мб и магию одного контейнера освоите =)

Comment: Что это "магия одного контейнера"? По такому запросу ничего не нашёл))

Comment: в грид контейнер при желании можно запихать почти все контент блоки без враперов, а после размазать все это по сетке как душе угодно парой тройкой строк. после того трэша который в БЭМе творится, выглядеть это всё будет как самая настоящая магия))) жаль только у гридов с анимацией не все так просто...

Comment: А где можно посмотреть-почитать об этом более подробно? Звучит интересно, но пока, не совсем понятно

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template обязательно потыкайте интерактивный пример=) там же в боковой панели слева загляните в каждое свойство с префиксом `grid-`. ну ладно не каждое но хотя бы grid-template, grid-area, grid-template-areas, grid-auto-flow.

Comment: А я бы не советовал использовать такие конструкторы, он криво делают вёрстку. Типа сделают норм на глаз, но лучше не смотреть в код)). И если кто-то за вас сделает вёрстку, поверьте сложнее поправлять сделанное, чем с нуля верстать самому.